# Modulus of continuity of a periodic absolute value function

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be a real function defined by $f(x)=|x|$ on $[-1,1]$ and $f(x)=f(x+2)$. How to prove analytically that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq|x-y|$?

If $|x-y|\geq1$ then the inequality clearly holds. But what if $|x-y|<1$? It becomes obvious by sliding $[x,y]$ to $[x+\delta,y+\delta]$ so that $f([x+\delta,y+\delta])$ lies entirely on a straight segment. How do I show this without appealing to geometric intuition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Let $g(x)=1$ for $0 \leq x <1$ and $g(x)=-1$ for $-1 \leq x <0$. Verify that $f(x)=\int_0^{x} g(t)dt$ for all $x$ by verying (using induction) that this holds for $x \in (2n-1,2n+1)$ for every integer $n$. The inequality is now obvious.